# Does this JavaScript code follow the Midpoint Displacement algorithm?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to use the [Midpoint Displacement Algorithm](http://www.gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html) using JavaScript and `canvas` as recommended on [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9384/how-do-i-generate-terrain-like-that-of-scorched-earth/9386#9386).

The code below generates points where the array index is the `x` position and its value is the `y` position.

```
var createTerrain = function(chops, range) {
    chops = chops || 2;
    range = parseInt(range || 100); 

    if (chops > 8) return;

    var cycle = parseInt(width / chops);    

    for (var i = 0; i <= width; i += cycle) {

        var y = (height / 2) + getRandomNumber(-range, range);

        terrain[i] = y;

    }

    chops *= 2;
    range *= 0.5;
    createTerrain(chops, range);

}
```

`getRandomNumber()`'s arguments are `min` and `max`. `width` and `height` are respective of the `canvas`.

This produces something like...
[image: Canvas]

It seems pretty choppy, but that may just be how it is.

Have I got this algorithm right? If not, what is wrong, and can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should be able to smooth it out by reducing the random number range. Did you try that already?

Comment: @Matt Yeah, I tried a few things. I'm more interested if I have this algorithm correct first :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd say it does not look like mid-point displacement, simply because every segment should be getting a regular X axis length (you have nearly vertical segments). Have you tried to generate a simple 4-segment array? What does it look like?

Here is a short tutorial I wrote, you can see it in action: [Mid-point algorithm in Javascript](http://www.marvinlabs.com/2011/04/mid-point-algorithm-javascript/)

The source code:

```
function Terrain(segmentCount) {
    this.segmentCount = segmentCount;
    this.points = [];
    for (i=0; i<=segmentCount; ++i) {
        this.points[i] = 0;
    }
};

/**
* Generate the terrain using the mid-point displacement algorithm. This is in fact
* a shortcut to the recursive function with the appropriate value to start
* generating the terrain.
*
* @param maxElevation the maximal vertical displacement to apply at this iteration
* @param sharpness how much to attenuate maxElevation at each iteration (lower
*        value means a smoother terrain). Keep between 0 and 1.
*/
Terrain.prototype.generateUsingMidPoint = function(maxElevation, sharpness) {
    this.midPoint(0, this.segmentCount, maxElevation, sharpness);
}

/**
* This is the recursive function to actually generate the terrain. It computes a new height for the point
* between "start" and "end" (the mid-point): averages start and end heights and adds a random
* displacement.
*
* @param maxElevation the maximal vertical displacement to apply at this iteration
* @param sharpness how much to attenuate maxElevation at each iteration (lower
*        value means a smoother terrain). Keep between 0 and 1.
*/
Terrain.prototype.midPoint = function(start, end, maxElevation, sharpness) {
    var middle = Math.round((start + end) * 0.5);
    if ((end-start<=1) || middle==start || middle==end) {
        return;
    }

    var newAltitude = 0.5 * (this.points[end] + this.points[start]) + maxElevation*(1 - 2*Math.random());
    this.points[middle] = newAltitude;

    this.midPoint(start, middle, maxElevation*sharpness, sharpness);
    this.midPoint(middle, end, maxElevation*sharpness, sharpness);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you have implemented is clearly wrong, from looking at the result. Where you went wrong is hard to say, since the code you have posted is not self contained. You are operating on several variables defined in a parent scope and it is not immediately apparent what they contain or how they behave.

What is `terrain` for example?

What you have to realize first of all is, that if the start and endpoints don't match on the y-axis you have done something wrong ;)